# Validation of price in Javascript using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to check whether a string is valid price or not. In some locales, "." is interchanged with "," and separator could be at thousands or hundreds.
For Example:
Valid:

```
1234  
1,234
1.234  
1,23,334
1.23.334 
1,23,334.00
1.23.334,00
```

Invalid:

```
1,23...233
1,,23
etc
```

The Regex I have used is

```
/(\d+(?:[\.,](?![\.,])\d+)*)/g
```

but this is giving me two matches for "1,23...233" i,e "1,23" and "233" as matches, I don't want to return any matches for that. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/xZ9yW0/1) is the regex I have been working on. What I actually want to do, whenever there is "." or "," next character should not be "." or "," and it should be a digit.

Comment: Seems to me `!/\.\.|,,/.test(string)` should do the job. If you also want to check that everything else is a digit, then: `!/\.\.|,,|\D/.test(string)`. The expressions return false if any of the patterns is found, otherwise true.

Comment: You should use plugin here instead of the Regex.

Comment: @anubhava , That seems fine for checking. What if we need to pick the price from, let's say "123,456.00 USD"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this.

```
^\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/61

```
var re = /^\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*$/gm;
var str = '1234\n1,234\n1.234\n1,23,334\n1.23.334\n1,23,334.00\n1.23.334,00\n1,23...233\n1,23.';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: @rahmanisback can be fixed easily (?!0[.,]) Put this at start

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xZ9yW0/2)

OR

```
^(?!.*(,,|,\.|\.,|\.\.))[\d.,]+$
```

Negative lookahead at the start asserts that the sting won't contain consecutive commas or dots or dots and commas.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xZ9yW0/4)